# How numpy manages offset of vector?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2 x 3 matrix [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]].

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)
>>> a.strides
(24, 8)
```

Now I set `a[1]` to a variable `b`, which is `[4, 5, 6]` . But I know this is a view of `a`. `b.base` is the same as `a` but shape and strides are changed.

```
>>> b = a[1]
>>> b.base
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> b.shape
(3,)
>>> b.strides
(8,)
```

My question is, how numpy manages `b` starts from `4` of `a`? I think some properties in `np.array` holds this information, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3):

It's determined by `data` which is a [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memoryview.html):

```
>>> b.data                                                                                                          
<memory at 0x11021c580>

>>> a.data                                                                                                          
<memory at 0x10c295930>
```

In other words, even though `b.base` refers to the original `a`, that is not what the shape and strides refer to.  The shape and strides say how to interpret `data`, not `base`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the offset with:

```
(  b.__array_interface__['data'][0]
 - a.__array_interface__['data'][0]) / b.strides[0]
```

Output: `3.0`

Another example:

```
a = np.arange(3*5).reshape(3, -1)
b = a[2]

(  b.__array_interface__['data'][0]
 - a.__array_interface__['data'][0]) / b.strides[0]
```

Output: `10.0`

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
#        ↑ 11th item
```